# get headers from angular with httpClient.get()

Tags: angular, get, header

**response in postman**

200 ok

body:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Workspace</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="styles.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

in angular

```
getParamsFromHeaders(): Observable<any> {

  return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:4200/').pipe(
    catchError(err => {

      return throwError(err);

  })
);
```

}

response angular

error because am recibe a html content... and i can access to the headers.

there is a way to void the error?

**greeatings**

Comment: Could you try specifying the responseType? `http.get<U>(url, {responseType: text'}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to observe the entire response as described below:

Here are your imports:-

---

```
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

---

Here is your function used in service.

---

```
getParamsFromHeaders() : Observable<HttpResponse<Object>>{

   return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/', { observe: 'response' }).pipe
(tap(resp => console.log('heaeder', r`enter code here`esp.headers.getAll('content-type')))
    );
}
```